# Cache entire jquery.min.js file in HTML5 localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have been trying to use localstorage to store Jquery-min but I am unable to do it. I have tried some of the Jquery plugins and they do not work either.

It just seems like a great idea to load Jquery once for my web application and never worry about it again. The application that I am creating has people that visit everyday. I do not think it is needed for them to download the JS files or CSS files more than once.

I am able to store all CSS in localstorage, but not Jquery or Jquery UI.

Anyway, I know people are going to try and convence me to use cache manifest....etc. But I am looking for a way to store the Jquery library in localstorage. (That is the goal).

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Everyone was asking for a code example. So here it is....it is pretty straight forward, i am only using a small--small amount of the Jquery minified version in order to keep the post small:

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "(function(a,b){function cy(a){return f.isWindow(a)?a:a.nodeType===9?a.defaultView||a.parentWindow:!1}function cv(a){if(!cj[a]){var b=f('<'+a+'>').appendTo('body'),d=b.css('display');b.remove();if(d==='none'||d===''){ck||(ck=c.createElement('iframe'),ck.frameBorder=ck.width=ck.height=0),c.body.appendChild(ck);if(!cl||!ck.createElement)cl=(ck.contentWindow||ck.contentDocument).document,cl.write('<!doctype><html><body></body>");
```

**What is saved when viewing it:**

```
(function(a,b){function cy(a){return f.isWindow(a)?a:a.nodeType===9?a.defaultView||a.parentWindow:!1}function cv(a){if(!cj[a]){var b=f('<'+a+'>').appendTo('body'),d=b.css('display');b.remove();if(d==='none'||d===''){ck||(ck=c.createElement('iframe'),ck.frameBorder=ck.width=ck.height=0),c.body.appendChild(ck);if(!cl||!ck.createElement)cl=(ck.contentWindow||ck.contentDocument).document,cl.write('
```

It does not save everything. Can I use a parsefloat() or something? How would I do that if it would work?

The reason I like local storage is that I can control it easy. And I don't have to worry about users emptying their cache. If I need to update localstorage I can do it with one line of code. It almost acts as an update feature for my web application. Please let me know if I am missing something or if there is an easier way to do this. Sample code coming soon

Comment: Are you getting a particular error? Tell us more about what you mean by "not able to."

Comment: Don't store your CSS or JS in localstorage. This isn't what it's designed for. Set appropriate `Expires` headers, and let the browser handle the caching.

I know you said you expected this, but really, it's not worth your time to try to do this yourself when browsers are designed to handle exactly this problem. Just set the expiry date to a year in the future, and you're done.

Comment: Second the Expires header, maybe even use a free CDN like google - http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Comment: The error I think I am getting is that localstorage requires a string. And the jquery libraries are not strings. There must be a way to resolve this.

Comment: I have to agree with @Michael Mior; perhaps it would help if you could clarify with a use case?

Comment: The reason I like local storage is that I can control it easy. And I don't have to worry about users emptying their cache. If I need to update localstorage I can do it with one line of code. It almost acts as an update feature for my web application. Please let me know if I am missing something or if there is an easier way to do this. Sample code coming soon.

Comment: Quick Note: Are you escaping all the quotes in the jQuery source? If not, then that's probably where your error is coming from.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to do that on the first code sample as I was doing it fast, but I did it now and you can see the output...sorry for that.

Comment: This is usually done by setting far-future `Expires` headers, then changing filenames or appending a simple version string. e.g. to force an update, you would change the referenced file from `myscript.js` to `myscript.js?version=2`.

Comment: @mitch I understand that you want control, but how would you handle versioning of your files? How can you detect that a new version of JQuery should be stored locally, and where do you get it from once you know?

Comment: I have a 'potentially' good use case for this. iBooks Author doesn't seem to have a location for shared files across multiple widgets so if I want to use jQuery and have 200 instances of a widget in my book I need to package jquery in with each widget. However it does support localstorage so if I add jQuery to localstorage via a starter widget, i can then use plain js to reference it in each widget and then use jQuery. The main issue I see is how to make sure the user has opened the first widget that sets jquery in localstorage in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine if you Base64 encode your script file before saving it to localstorage. In the sample below I left out the jQuery file, but in the demo the whole jQuery 1.7 is encoded.

I used the following site to encode the whole file as one string (most break it into chunks): http://textmechanic.co/ASCII-Hex-Unicode-Base64-Converter.html?type=text

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/ZMAKn

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

Script:

```
var jquery = '<Base64 encoded file>';
var result = 'jQuery: ' + ( typeof $ != 'undefined' ) + '<br />';

window.localStorage.setItem( 'jquery', jquery );
jquery = '';
jquery = window.localStorage.getItem( 'jquery' );

eval( atob( jquery ) );

result += 'jQuery: ' + ( typeof $ != 'undefined' ) + '<br />';

$( 'div' ).html( result ); //this works, so jQuery loaded

window.localStorage.removeItem( 'jquery' );
```

Output:

```
jQuery: false
jQuery: true
```

Answer (score 3):

This was a great exercise and all for HTML5 local storage, but shouldn't your web server just respond with an HTTP 304 (Not Modified)?  Just about all web servers since 1998 support this feature.  It would be much faster to have your server respond with a simple 304 than to write gobs of javascript to load jQuery in and out of local storage.

And if for some reason you can't get your web server to work, use one of the [public jQuery CDNs](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) where they will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cyan Lite. You need to use browser caching for this, not waste time encoding it.

If you don't want to use a CDN as Cyan suggested, you can easily enable caching on your server: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching